# Where is a TelnetConsole object constructed in Scrapy?

Tags: scrapy

I'm running `Scrapy` from scripts, and found that `logging` doesn't work as expected from the point it constructs a `scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole` object. Thus, I tried to find where the object is constructed from the source files, but I couldn't.

Where does `Scrapy` construct a `scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole` object when it is run from scripts?

Answer (score 1):

`TelnetConsole` is a scrapy extension that allows to connect to scrapy processes via telnet:

> Telnet is an application protocol used on the Internet or local area network to provide a bidirectional interactive text-oriented communication facility using a virtual terminal connection. User data is interspersed in-band with Telnet control information in an 8-bit byte oriented data connection over the Transmission Control Protocol (TCP).

It allows you to do many things like inspect python objects and even pause/resume crawling.
see more at the extensive official [docs for TelnetConsole extension](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/telnetconsole.html)

It is constructed in the extensions initiation step.
To disable it you can simply set `TELNETCONSOLE_ENABLED` settings to `False` in your `settings.py` or when running your crawler:

```
scrapy crawl myspider -s TELNETCONSOLE_ENABLED=False
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind explanation of `TelnetConsole`. For now, I'm interested why logs start to be routed to `STDOUT` from the point it prints "...[scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password ...", even though `LOG_FILE` is specified in my settings. Could you tell me where `the extensions initiation step` is written in source files? I tried to find by `grep -r TelenetConsole` from `scrapy` source files directory, but I couldn't find any clues.

Comment: It's hard to tell but `TelnetConsole` is definitely not your culprit here.